# Why my ESLint configuration file do not work with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, eslint, eslintrc

Using VSCode, i created a React Native app using expo-cli. I want to use ESLint and Prettier to improve my code quality.
I expected ESLint printed out error in my Problems tab, e.g if i had this line `var asd = 1;` in App.js ESLint will print out `Unexpected var, use let or const instead.`
I had ESLint config file setup, i intentionally code wrong to test if ESLint is working, but i did not see any errors.
ESLint for VSCode has already been installed with version 1.9.1 and in the link contains my [project's structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2Ka2.png).

This is my App.js code with 2 places i expect to generate errors:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

var asd = 1; // this should show error

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});

const zzz = StyleSheet.create({
  // this should show error based on react-native/no-unused-styles rule in eslint config
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

This is my .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "prettier",
    "plugin:node/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["prettier", "react", "react-native"],
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "react-native/react-native": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "warn",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-console": "off",
    "func-names": "off",
    "no-process-exit": "off",
    "no-alert": "warn",
    "object-shorthand": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off",
    "no-plusplus": ["error", { "allowForLoopAfterthoughts": true }],
    "react-native/no-unused-styles": "error"
  },
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".ios.js", ".android.js"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have ESLint extension installed in your VSCode?

Comment: what Ziyo said https://dev.to/iamdammak/setting-up-eslint-in-your-javascript-project-with-vs-code-2amf

Comment: Yes, my version is 1.9.1.

Comment: i realise you didnt have the `root` prop in place nor set it to be true. is there another .eslintrc.json file somewhere else in the project directory?

Comment: @kenmistry I think no, i am pretty sure there is only 1 .eslintrc.json in this project. I have updated my post including a picture showing my project's structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My `parserOptions` in the config file is not details enough. I need to update it like below:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "ecmaVersion": 6,
  "sourceType": "module",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
  }
},
```

Comment: Which config file?

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this in **.eslintrc.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: '@react-native',
};
```